# Is there a way to persistently disable the menu bar in Konsole on Gnome 3?

Tags: gnome, gui, konsole

I'm running Konsole 16.08.3-1 (installed via `pacman`) as my default terminal emulator under Gnome 3.22.2. Normally, when I start Konsole, I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to hide the menu bar; I only sparingly use it, and generally the white menu bar distracts from my overall dark terinal.

Is there any way to hide the menu bar persistently so that I don't have to hide it manually every time I start Konsole?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are actually two different settings. The one you described in your question, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> or *Settings > Show Menubar* is for the current window only.

You can disable the menubar for newly created windows permanently by unchecking *Settings > Configure Konsole > General > Show menubar by default* or by changing/adding

```
[KonsoleWindow]
ShowMenuBarByDefault=false
```

to *~/.config/konsolerc*

Answer (score 1):

Try rigth-click on the title bar space, there is an option that says "Hide menu bar", make sure its checked.

Alternatively, you can add the the  `--hide-menubar` flag to the execution command from whatever place that yuou are running konsole from, that will override the default behaviour.

One more is editing the startup configuration file of Konsole in
`~/.kde4/share/config/konsolerc`

Read this doc for further information (search for menubar):
https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/konsole/konsole.pdf

Comment: `there is an option that says "Hide menu bar"` I explained in my question that this is already what I'm doing, and it's not persistent. As for the `--hide-menubar` option -- I'm just launching Konsole as a GUI application from Gnome. I'm not sure how to hook into that to pass flags.

Comment: If you are pressing an icon to launch it, try right clicking that icon and selecting properties or something similar, I'm guessing that there must somewhere some place to modify the command that is executed when you click the icon.

Comment: I just added a 3rd way to do it, in my answer.

Comment: Alright, what do I edit the `konsolerc` with?

Comment: With any text editor you may have in your system, I think for Gnome you must have gedit. You could also do it from Konsole itself using nano, for example.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding me. I'm familiar with text editors (I use Neovim); what do I put in the `konsolerc` file? It's not specified in the manual you linked to.

Comment: Oh, I apologize about that. I am sorry I do not have access to my linux machine right now, but if you read the konsolerc file you might find the appropriate section to write `Menubar=hidden` and see if that solves your problem.